# What kind of .lib file begins with "!<arch>"?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I have a .lib file, just wondering what compiler it's from: it begins with "!<arch>" ?

Thanks

Comment: Try passing it through the unix `file` utility?

Comment: This is a windows system

Comment: However, objdump + cygwin works wonders!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!<arch>` sounds like an [ar archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)).

Comment: Fantastic. I renamed it to .tar, and was able to open it with 7zip. It contained a bunch of *.o files

Comment: I *knew* sitting around in college discussing the binary structure of Debian packages, 13 years ago, would someday pay off!

Comment: @Chris: please I need your help on using .lib files in MS Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

the .lib file are generally build with Visual C++ compiler. In the linux environment gcc generate .a and .so file but no .lib file.